# VS 2017 - Trying to Open Excel 2010 document to edit using VB.net - "No such interface supported"

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, com

I am trying to write an application using vb.net on VS 2017 to open and edit an Excel document for use on many computers of varying Windows versions (7, 8, 10 etc) and Microsoft Office installations (2010,'13 etc). I am writing this application on a Windows 7 computer, and my office version is 2010. However, when I run the code I get this error message:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks'. This operation failed
>   because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface
>   with IID '{000208DB-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the
>   following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

The following is my code:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1
    Dim GlobalProjectLoc As String
    Dim FileLoc As String

    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim excelWB As Excel.Workbooks
    Dim excelWS As Excel.Worksheet

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        GlobalProjectLoc = "C:\Users\Documents\VBA\"
        FileLoc = GlobalProjectLoc & "Excel File to Edit"

        excelApp = New Excel.Application
        excelWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(FileLoc)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have added both the `Microsoft Office 14.0 Object Library` and `Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library` to my references. I have found similar error messages to mine online, however, when the registry was searched for the CLSID in the error message, the user seemed to be able to find a fault in their registry with a double entry of versions. In my case, when I search my registry for "000208DB-0000-0000-C000-000000000046", I get no results.

When I installed VS 2017, I installed the following packages with it: Universal Windows Platform development, .NET desktop development and Desktop development with C++. Am I missing an important one?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have spent hours trawling through forums trying to see if the solution that worked for somebody with a similar problem to me would apply to my case, but so far I've had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Dim excelWB As Excel.Workbooks` to `Dim excelWB As Excel.Workbook` and try again.

Comment: Yes that stopped the error message, but now the Excel file still doesn't open and there are no error messages present. Have I another problem with my code? I checked the task manager and Excel is not running in the applications section when I run the code. The path to the file of interest is definitely correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "_Excel file still doesn't open_"? Are you trying to view the file? If so, try `excelApp.Visible = True`. If not, try checking if **EXCEL.EXE *32** is running under Task Manager. Also, add the code where you are handling this opened Excel file.

Comment: In all my frustration with this, I forgot some very simple Excel VBA. Worked a treat, much appreciated, thank you!